# Assigning one of two values to a random integer

Tags: python

Currently, I am simulating a 6 sided dice roll with

```
import random    
print("Let's roll the dice")
print(random.randint(1,6))
```

I would like to assign a different values to each roll.  Numbers 1,2,3 should be 5/4 and 4,5,6 should be 10/2.  How would I go about doing this?  I've tried this, but it didn't assign the desired value.

```
import random    
print("Let's roll the dice")
dice=print(random.randint(1,6))
    if  dice == '1': print("10/2")
    if  dice == '3': print("10/2")
    if  dice == '2': print("10/2")
    if  dice == '4': print("5/4")
    if  dice == '5': print("5/4")
    if  dice == '6': print("5/4")
```

Comment: `print()` always returns `None`. And you also have an indentation issue.

Answer (score 0):

`print()` doesn't return the value, but `None` so `dice` will get `None` and therefore your if-statements will fail (assuming the indentation was correct)

---

Assign the random int to `dice` (remove `print()`)

Use a simple `if` to create a new var:

```py
import random    

print("Let's roll the dice")
dice=random.randint(1,6)

customDice = '10/2' if dice <= 3 else '5/4'

print(customDice)
```

Answer (score -2):

```py
import random
  
print("Let's roll the dice")
dice = random.randint(1,6)
if dice in (1, 2, 3):
    print("10/2")
elif dice in (4, 5, 6):
    print("5/4")
```

Glad to help

Comment: `dice` will always be `None` here.